# Aplicação AngularJs funciona no Chrome, mas no IE não funciona

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma aplicação web C#, com uma página com dados de cliente. Ao alterar os dados utilizando o Chrome e depois salvar, os dados salvam no banco de dados e, via tela, são atualizados corretamente. Ao fazer o mesmo no IE, a página retorna que salvou, porém, via tela, não ocorre a atualização, mas no banco de dados a alteração foi efetuada.

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cliente Sem Código no Itaú";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_master.cshtml";
}

<div class="container" ng-controller="clienteSemCodigo">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a ng-show="cliente === null">
                Busca
            </a>
            <a ng-show="cliente !== null">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                {{cliente.Nome}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-panel active" id="divBusca">
            @* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *@
            @* Filtro *@
            <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-hide="cliente !== null">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFiltro">
                    <strong>Filtros</strong> <small class="pull-right">Cliente sem código no Itaú</small>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFiltro" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel"
                     ng-class="{'in': cliente === null}">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="frmBusca" novalidate>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Código do cliente</span>
                                        <input type="number" id="txtCodigoCliente" placeholder="Código" ng-model="filtroCliente.CodigoBovespa" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Nome</span>
                                        <input type="text" id="txtNomeCliente" placeholder="Nome" ng-model="filtroCliente.Nome" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="ObterClientes(1)">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                        Filtrar
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *@
            @* Alerta: Cliente nao encontrados *@
            <div ng-show="clientes.length === 0 && cliente === null">
                <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
                    Nenhum cliente para exibição
                </div>
            </div>
            @* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *@
            @* Lista de Clientes Encontrados *@
            <div class="panel panel-default" ng-show="clientes !== null && clientes.length !== 0 && cliente === null">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped align-all-center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Código</th>
                                <th style="text-align:left">Nome</th>
                                <th>Tipo Pessoa</th>
                                <th>CPF/CNPJ</th>
                                <th>Gestor</th>
                                <th>Agência</th>
                                <th style="width:10%">Conta</th>
                                <th>Código Assessor</th>
                                <th>Editar</th>
                                <th>Excluir</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="c in clientes">
                                <td>
                                    {{ c.CodigoBovespa }}
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">
                                    {{ c.Nome }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ c.TipoPessoa == 0 ? "PF" : "PJ" }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ c.CpfCnpj | cpfCnpj}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ c.CodigoGestor }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ c.CodigoAgencia }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ c.CodigoConta + "-" + c.DigitoConta  }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ c.CodigoAssessor }}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" ng-click="EditarClienteItau(c)" class="btn btn-primary" title="Clique aqui para editar todos os campos">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" ng-click="ExcluirCliente(c)" class="btn btn-primary" title="Clique aqui para excluir o cliente" ng-click="ExcluirCliente(c)">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot ng-show="gridPrincipal.totalDePaginas > 1">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="10">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <div class="pull-left">
                                                <small>Página <kbd>{{ gridPrincipal.paginaAtual }}</kbd> de <kbd>{{ gridPrincipal.totalDePaginas }}</kbd></small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                            <div class="input-group">                                                
                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" ng-show="(gridPrincipal.paginaAtual > 1) && (gridPrincipal.totalDePaginas > 1)"
                                                            ng-click="ObterClientes(gridPrincipal.paginaAtual-1)">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </span>
                                                <select ng-model="gridPrincipal.paginaAtual" class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="ObterClientes()"
                                                        ng-options="page for page in range(gridPrincipal.totalDePaginas)"></select>

                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" ng-show="(gridPrincipal.paginaAtual !== gridPrincipal.totalDePaginas) && (gridPrincipal.totalDePaginas > 1)"
                                                            ng-click="ObterClientes(gridPrincipal.paginaAtual+1)">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            @* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *@
            @* Cliente Detalhado *@
            <div class="panel panel-info" ng-show="cliente !== null">
                <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                    <h4 class="pull-left">
                        <strong>Cliente Itaú</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Voltar()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
                            Voltar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    @* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *@
                    @* Dados do Cliente no Itáu *@
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Código Bovespa</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="number" ng-model="cliente.CodigoBovespa" class="form-control" placeholder="Código">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="cliente.Nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" maxlength="30">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo Pessoa</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">                                                                                                                            
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="cliente.TipoPessoa"
                                        ng-options="t.Codigo as t.Descricao for t in tipoPessoa">                                    
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">CPF/CNPJ</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input-cpf-cnpj id="txtCpfCnpj" cpf-cnpj-model="cliente.CpfCnpj"></input-cpf-cnpj>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Código do Gestor</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="number" ng-model="cliente.CodigoGestor" class="form-control" placeholder="Código">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Conta</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">

                                @* /////////////////////////////////////////// *@
                                @* Area: Conta *@
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                Agência
                                                            </span>
                                                            <input type="number" ng-model="cliente.CodigoAgencia" class="form-control" placeholder="Código">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                Código
                                                            </span>
                                                            <input type="number" ng-model="cliente.CodigoConta" class="form-control" placeholder="Código">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                                Dígito
                                                            </span>
                                                            <input type="number" ng-model="cliente.DigitoConta" class="form-control" placeholder="Código">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Código do Assessor</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="number" ng-model="cliente.CodigoAssessor" class="form-control" placeholder="Código">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-10 col-sm-2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="Salvar()">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                                    Salvar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>                        
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/js/app/Itau/ClienteSemCodigo.js")
}
@section styles{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Itau/ClienteSemCodigo.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

Comment: Mostra o código que vc já fez, apenas de frontend.

Comment: Roda um [jslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jslint) no seu código, deve ajudar a identificar algum problema.

Comment: Tem alguma mensagem no console do browser?

Comment: Não aparece nenhuma mensagem no browser, editei a pergunta e coloquei o front, estou usando angularjs tambem.

Comment: Agora esta aparecendo erro no console :SCRIPT5: Acesso negado.